# getElemntById query for JavaScript

Tags: javascript

can you please tell me why this wouldnt work? been stuck at it all day.

I just wanna copy whatever is enetered in the first  field, convert it to a variable and project it to the last

field.

Thank you

ps: needless to say i only copied the relevant bits of the code...

```
<th bgcolor="#eeeee" width=12.5%>Monday</th>
        <th bgcolor="#eeeee" width=12.5%><input id="test" value="09:15" size=15></td></th>
        <th bgcolor="#eeeee" width=12.5%><input type=time id="Monday_Breakfast_LastSeating" value="11:45" size=15></td></th>

    </form>
    </table>

    <form id="form2" id=other method=POST>




        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#aaeeaa"align=center><button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button></td>

        </tr>

    </form>


    <table width=40%  border=0>

        <th bgcolor="#eeaaaa" align=center width=33%>Goal</th>

    </table>

    <form id=result method=POST>
    <table width=40% border=0>

        <th style="border:black;" bgcolor="#eeaaaa" align=center><em></em> <p id="calculation2" size=15>N/A</p></th>
        <th bgcolor="#eeaaaa" align=center><em></em> <p id="calculation3" size=15>N/A</p></th>
        <th bgcolor="#eeaaaa" align=center><p id="calc" size=15>N/A</p></th>

    </table>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {

        var test = getElementById("test").value;
        document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = test;
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Your `table` looks weird. That's not what it should be like

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. That is the start of your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! Gaby aka G. Petrioli, marteljn, Marc B, Aelios

Comment: Highly recommend you to use Firefox, you can start Page Inspector in Firefox with Ctrl+Shift+K, [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) addon is great to find bugs in your javascript, and [html validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/). Very useful plugins. Hope this will help you: [valid html and javascript example](http://pastebin.com/GThbzLh5) Good luck!

Comment: Great, needs much coding to do, but at least it's valid html :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `document.` before the first `getElementById`

```
function myFunction() {
  var test = document.getElementById("test").value; // you forgot the document. here..
  document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = test;
}
```

Additionally, there is not `size` attribute for `p` elements. (*perhaps you wanted to use `input` elements.. But for those you should use the `value` property instead of the `innerHTML` to set them..*)

Comment: Hey, thank you, it works, for like a milisecond, then it pops back to N/A. any ideas, why it wouldnt stay permanently there?

Comment: @Csongor yes.. Add `type="button"` on the button element. Otherwise it is treated as a submit button and submits the form (*making the page reload..*)

Comment: and yeah that's precisely what happened. I used input type elements first :)

Answer (score 1):

Change  `var test = getElementById("test").value;` to `var test = document.getElementById("test").value;`

Comment: Hey Marteljn, thank you, your solution works as well, however, only for like a milisecond, then it pops back to N/A. any ideas, why it wouldnt stay permanently there?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
document.getElementById('calc').innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').value;
```

`getElementById()` by itself is not a valid function